# Right Click Save HTML Canvas Image

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, canvas

Right clicking and saving image as is simple in google chrome as the canvas is treated like an `<Img>` element. But it almost any other browser when you right click on a canvas it doesn't give you the option to save. How do I get around this I need a way the user can save a canvas on a page, or how do I allow the right click and save image as option in browsers like IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Chrome & Firefox will let you right-click-save-canvas-as-image. Other browsers don't.

Here's a classic way of opening up a canvas-->image new browser tab for other browsers:

```
mySaveButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var html="<p>Right-click on image below and Save-Picture-As</p>";
    html+="<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"' alt='from canvas'/>";
    var tab=window.open();
    tab.document.write(html);
});
```

Comment: the code above doesn't work it leaves my canvas blank

Comment: This code works for me in IE & Edge. The typical cause of a blank image created with `.toDataURL` is that the canvas has been tainted by a cross-domain image drawn to the canvas. Open the F12 developer tools, refresh your page and look at the Console tab to see if you have a security error.

Comment: It says its missing ")" and when I add that it says its missing "{" and I am using Edge right now. Would it help if i sent the code I am using to create the canvas? @markE

Comment: Lifesaver thanks, I think I have had just about enough of the html canvas element. :)